# Why does sed not replace overlapping patterns

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a database unload file with field separated with the <TAB> character. I am running this file through sed to replace any occurences of <TAB><TAB> with <TAB>\N<TAB>. This is so that when the file is loaded into MySQL the \N in interpreted as NULL.

The sed command 's/\t\t/\t\N\t/g;' almost works except that it only replaces the first instance e.g.  "...<TAB><TAB><TAB>..." becomes "...<TAB>\N<TAB><TAB>...".

If I use 's/\t\t/\t\N\t/g;s/\t\t/\t\N\t/g;' it replaces more instances.

I have a notion that despite the /g modifier this is something to do with the end of one match being the start of another.

Could anyone explain what is happening and suggest a sed command that would work or do I need to loop.

I know I could probably switch to awk, perl, python but I want to know what is happening in sed.

Comment: If you can specify an obvious answer to what should happen when replacements overlap, I'm sure that would receive a lot of attention. What would happen in your "parallel" sed if the input was _a_ and the substitutions `s/a/b/&s/b/a/` were requested? (I am using & as the command separator to indicate that both should happen at the same time.)

Comment: Another problem is the infinite loop: `s/something/something or other/` and `sed` takes a very long time to run (or, more accurately, it runs out of memory)!

Comment: Thanks @triplee when you put it like that it becomes patently obvious when you consider that rescanning the line could introduce a loop.

Comment: It should be noted the since if `\t`=`a` and `\N`=`b` then `aaa` on the first subsitution will be replaced by `abaa` and by `ababa` in the second. Thus no loop is needed to replace all cases, just two applications of the same global substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you want sed, but sed doesn't like this at all, it seems that it specifically (see [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-7)) won't do what you want.  However, perl will do it (AFAIK):

```
perl -pe 'while (s#\t\t#\t\n\t#) {}' <filename>
```

Comment: Maybe this to ensure trailing nulls don't get treated as empty strings? (note that I replaced \n with \\N) perl -pe 'while (s#\t\t#\t\\Nt#) {}' -pe 's/\t$/\t\\N/g'

Comment: Perl supports positive lookahead, so `perl -pe 's|\t(?=\t)|\t\n|g'` works

Answer (score 4):

Not dissimilar to the perl solution, this works for me using pure sed

With @Robin A. Meade improvement

```
sed ':repeat;
     s|\t\t|\t\n\t|g;
     t repeat'
```

### Explanation

- `:repeat` is a label, used for branch commands, similar to batch
- `s|\t\t|\t\n\t|g;` - Standard replace 2 tabs with tab-newline-tab. I still use the global flag because if you have, say, 15 tabs, you will only need to loop twice, rather than 14 times.
- `t repeat` means if the "s" command did any replaces, then goto the label `repeat`, else it goes onto the next line and starts over again.

So it goes like this. Keep repeating (goto `repeat`) as long as there is a match for the pattern of 2 tabs.

While the argument can be made that you could just do two identical global replaces and call it good, this same technique could work in more complicated scenarios.

As @thorn-blake points out, sed just doesn't support advanced features like lookahead, so you need to do a loop like this.

**Original Answer**

```
sed ':repeat;
     /\t\t/{
       s|\t\t|\t\n\t|g;
       b repeat
     }'
```

### Explanation

- `:repeat` is a label, used for branch commands, similar to batch
- `/\t\t/` means match the pattern 2 tabs. If the pattern it matched, the command following the second / is executed.
- `{}` - In this case the command following the match command is a group. So all of the commands in the group are executed if the match pattern is met.
- `s|\t\t|\t\n\t|g;` - Standard replace 2 tabs with tab-newline-tab. I still use the global because if you have say 15 tabs, you will only need to loop twice, rather than 14 times.
- `b repeat` means always goto (branch) the label `repeat`

### Short version

Which can be shortened to

```
sed ':r;s|\t\t|\t\n\t|g; t r'

# Original answer
# sed ':r;/\t\t/{s|\t\t|\t\n\t|g; b r}'
```

---

## MacOS

And the Mac (yet still Linux/Windows compatible) version:

```
sed $':r\ns|\t\t|\t\\\n\t|g; t r'

# Original answer
# sed $':r\n/\t\t/{ s|\t\t|\t\\\n\t|g; b r\n}'
```

- Tabs need to be literal in BSD sed
- Newlines need to be both literal and escaped at the same time, hence the single slash (that's \ before it is processed by the $, making it a single literal slash ) plus the \n which becomes an actual newline
- Both label names (:r) and branch commands (b r when not the end of the expression) must end in a newline. Special characters like semicolons and spaces are consumed by the label name/branch command in BSD, which makes it all very confusing.

Comment: Can your solution be simplified to `sed ':repeat; s|\t\t|\t\n\t|g; t repeat'` by changing the [branch command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-Flow-Control) from unconditional, `b` to conditional, `t`.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, replace every tab with tab + \N; then remove all occurrences of \N which are not immediately followed by a tab.

```
sed -e 's/\t/\t\\N/g' -e 's/\\N\([^\t]\)/\1/g'
```

... provided your sed uses backslash before grouping parentheses (there are sed dialects which don't want the backslashes; try without them if this doesn't work for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Right, even with `/g`, sed will not match the text it replaced again.  Thus, it's read `<TAB><TAB>` and output `<TAB>\N<TAB>` and then reads the next thing in from the input stream.  See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-7

In a regex language that supports lookaheads, you can get around this with a lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `sed` simply works as designed. The input line is scanned once, not multiple times. Maybe it helps to look at the consequences if `sed` used rescanning the input line to deal with overlapping patterns by default: in this case even simple substitutions would work quite differently--some might say counter-intuitively--, e.g.

- `s/^/ /` inserting a space at the beginning of a line would never terminate
- `s/$/foo/` appending foo to each line - likewise
- `s/[A-Z][A-Z]*/CENSORED/` replacing uppercase words with CENSORED - likewise

There are probably many other situations. Of course these could all be remedied with, say, a substitution modifier, but at the time sed was designed, the current behavior was chosen.