# How can I regex ,, to ,\N, in my CSVs so that mysqlimport understands them?

Tags: mysql, regex, perl, csv, import

Say I have a normal CSV like

```
# helloworld.csv
hello,world,,,"please don't replace quoted stuff like ,,",,
```

If I want `mysqlimport` to understand that some of those fields are `NULL`, then I need:

```
# helloworld.mysql.csv
hello,world,\N,\N,"please don't replace quoted stuff like ,,",\N,\N
```

I got some help from another question -- [Why does sed not replace overlapping patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421114/why-does-sed-not-replace-overlapping-patterns) -- but note the problem:

```
$ perl -pe 'while (s#,,#,\\N,#) {}' -pe 's/,$/,\\N/g' helloworld.csv
hello,world,\N,\N,"please don't replace quoted stuff like ,\N,",\N,\N
                                                           ^^
```

How can I write the regex so it doesn't replace `,,` if they're between quotes?

**FINAL ANSWER**

Here's the final perl I used, thanks to the accepted answer below:

```
perl -pe 's/^,/\\N,/; while (s/,(?=,)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/,\\N/g) {}; s/,$/,\\N/' helloworld.csv
```

That takes care of leading, trailing, and unquoted empty strings.

Comment: Based on your accepted answer: I seriously doubt this regex will be easier to maintain than Text::CSV (or Text::CSV_XS), it is a very nice module, and can easily handle quoted strings. You are reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you won't have escaped quotes, you can make sure that you only replace `,,` if it's followed by an even number of quotes:

```
$subject =~ 
    s/,       # Match ,
    (?=,)     # only if followed by another ,
    (?=       # and only if followed by...
     (?:      # the following group:
      [^"]*"  #  any number of non-quote characters, followed by one quote
      [^"]*"  #  the same thing again (even number!)
     )*       # any number of times, followed by
     [^"]*    # any number of non-quotes until...
     $        # end of string.
    )         # End of lookahead assertion
    /,\N/x
    g;
```

Input:

```
foo,,bar,,,baz,"foo,,,oof",zap,,zip
```

Output:

```
foo,\N,bar,\N,\N,baz,"foo,,,oof",zap,\N,zip
```

Comment: when you say escaped, i think you mean slash-escaped. the csv standard (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180, section 2, item 3) specifies escaping with MORE double quotes. so - your solution still works - """,,",, => """,,",\N,\N

Comment: i added a condensed form of your answer above. thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

Why not use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV)? You can parse the file with it and then use `map` to replace empty fields with '\N', e.g.

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 }) or die Text::CSV->error_diag();
$csv->parse($line);           # parse a CSV string into fields
my @fields = $csv->fields();  # get the parsed fields

@fields = map { $_ eq "" ? '\N' : $_ } @fields;

$csv->combine(@fields);    # combine fields into a string
```

Comment: i wanted a one-liner, but you're right that this is an easier-to-maintain solution.